# Sub not continuing after another sub with msgbox.yesno is called

Tags: vb.net

I've been having a problem lately where if I call a sub with a msgbox.styleyesno, it won't go back to the original sub that called it.

This is my code:
Sub1:

```
Private Sub cmbLeegmaken_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbLeegmaken.SelectedIndexChanged
    Tabel_Leegmaken(cmbLeegmaken.Text)
    Hide_Leegmaken()
    Loadtable()
End Sub
```

Called sub:

```
Sub Tabel_Leegmaken(ByVal Tabelnaam As String)
    MsgBox("Weet je zeker dat je de tabel " & Tabelnaam & " volledig wilt leegmaken?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If vbYes Then
        Dim QuerVerwijdertabel As New SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " & Tabelnaam, connection)
        QuerVerwijdertabel.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is, that after the sub Tabel_Leegmaken ends, it won't return back to the "Private Sub cmbLeegmaken_SelectedIndexChanged".

I don't know if it has anything to do with the msgbox being called there or not, but I just can't seem to get it to work (even though it's probably some small mistake which I just can't seem to spot ><).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the top of your code or in project properties, set Option Strict On.  Then fix any errors that might appear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to write:

```
Sub Tabel_Leegmaken(ByVal Tabelnaam As String)
    If MsgBox("Weet je zeker dat je de tabel " & Tabelnaam & " volledig wilt leegmaken?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = vbYes Then
        Dim QuerVerwijdertabel As New SqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE " & Tabelnaam, connection)
        QuerVerwijdertabel.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to change the code in your MsgBox. I have tested the code as below which works fine:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    LaunchHere(ComboBox1.Text)
    MessageBox.Show("Back into Main ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged")
End Sub

Sub LaunchHere(ByVal abc As String)
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Hello from inside Launch", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Title")
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        MessageBox.Show("Inside Launch Here and used YES")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Inside Launch Here and used NO")
    End If
End Sub
```